# Evaluating List to Weak Head Normal Form

Tags: list, haskell

Given the following list from 1 to 100:

```
> let x = [1..100]
```

I run `sprint x` to observe its unevaluated value.

```
> :sprint x
x = _
```

Then, I ran `seq` to evaluate it to Weak Head Normal Form:

```
> seq x ()
()
```

But re-running `sprint x` shows (*what I think*) is the same value.

```
> :sprint x
x = _
```

Why is that?

Comment: What is the type of `x`?  If it's `(Num a, Enum a) => [a]` then this won't work as expected.  Try `let x = [1..100] :: [Int]`.  In reality, when you print `x` with the more general type GHCi specializes it to `Integer` to do the printing.  This means that the values you see printed are not actually stored back in `x`'s thunk.  Using a concrete type avoids this problem.

Comment: For once, a problem caused by the _lack_ of the dreaded monomorphism restriction! :-)

Comment: Well that's the usual bias of defaults: the disadvantages of the default are going to be more salient than the advantages.

Comment: I think @bheklilr comment should b ethe answer - just a small observation: when I red it, it almost look like the problem might be `Integer` vs `Int` - this is not a critique it's just that I thought for a moment: "is there something going on with `Integer`?) - so maybe you can just rename it to `[1..100] :: [Integer]`? (sorry)

Comment: By running this scenario myself, I got: `x = 1 : _` the second time.

Comment: @CommuSoft You must either be putting it into a file and then loading it or you're using a GHCi with a version before 7.8. The monomorphism restriction would be turned on in those cases.

Answer (score 1):

I think this bheklilr's comment should be marked as the answer:

> What is the type of x? If it's `(Num a, Enum a) => [a]` then this won't work as expected. Try `let x = [1..100] :: [Int`]. In reality, when you print x with the more general type GHCi specializes it to Integer to do the printing. This means that the values you see printed are not actually stored back in x's thunk. Using a concrete type avoids this problem.

With the additional note from David Young that this problem won't occur on GHCi versions earlier than 7.8, when the monomorphism restriction was enabled.