# Understanding `seq` with Example

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to understand `seq` with the following example:

```
Prelude> let x = 100 + 2
```

`sprint`-ing the value of `x` shows `_` since it has not been evaluated.

```
Prelude> :sprint x
x = _
```

Let's, as I understand `seq`, evaluate `x`.

```
Prelude> seq x ()
()
```

Now, let's check the value of `x`.

```
Prelude> :sprint x
x = _
```

Why hasn't `x` been evaluated to `102` after calling `seq x ()`?

Answer (score 1):

Same problem as your [last question earlier today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30899003/evaluating-list-to-weak-head-normal-form). The type of x is `Num a => a` (just try `:t x` in GHCi). You can't evaluate this until it is clear what `a` is. **There is no way of determining which `(+)` function should be used without knowing what `a` is, so `x` can't be evaluated past a thunk**. If `a` is `Int`, GHCi will call a different `(+)` function than if `a` is `Integer`.

For example, if you do `let x = 100 + 2 :: Integer` instead, then everything works like you expect it too. You get `x = _` before the call to `seq` and `x = 102` after.

The confusing bit is that if you just throw in `x` into GHCi, it'll give you back `102`. This is because GHCi specializes the type `a` from `x :: Num a => a` to `Integer`, allowing it to evaluate the value, then print it. But that has no effect on `x`.